# How can I tell which python source files are executed?

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage

One of my tests is failing. Although I have tons of source files, I know that only a few of them are used when I run the test.

How can I determine which files are used by in the test?

Comment: Have you multiple personalities disorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a full coverage report. See https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.2/

```
sudo pip install coverage
coverage run test.py test1
coverage html
gnome-www-browser htmlcov/index.html
```